# Pass several list into the Pytest parameterize

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to create a PyTest, that verifies the existence of my folders depending on env.

Is it possible to create a separate test using the parameterize for each folder?

| env | folder |
| --- | --- |
| dev | dev_data |
| dev | logs |
| dev | debug |
| prod | prod_data |

My code now looks something like that (but it's not working):

```
env = ["dev", "prod"]
expectedFoldersDev = ["dev_data", "logs", "debug"] # count of folders can be > 30
expectedFoldersProd = ["prod_data"]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("env, folder", [(env[0], expectedFoldersDev), 
                                             (env[1], expectedFoldersProd)])
                         
def test_are_folders_exist(env, folder):
    expected_folders = get_folders(env)
    assert folder in expected_folders

def get_folders():
   ...
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Have you seen my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70211752/4413446? I would be interested to have your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict` (`FOLDERS` in this example) to store your test values and define a method (`get_items` in this example) to expand it through a generator that can be passed directly to the `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator. Here is a working example.

```
import pytest


FOLDERS = {"dev": ["dev_data", "logs", "debug"], "prod": ["prod_data"]}


def get_items():
    for key, value in FOLDERS.items():
        for val in value:
            yield key, val


@pytest.mark.parametrize("env, folder", get_items())
def test_are_folders_exist(env, folder):
    print(f"Checking folder {folder} on env {env}...")
    expected_folders = get_folders(env)
    assert folder in expected_folders


def get_folders(env):
    # just for the example, it should be the method to be tested
    return FOLDERS.get(env)
```

It gives this output.

```sh
pytest -s folders.py
# fixture.py Checking folder dev_data on env dev...
# .Checking folder logs on env dev...
# .Checking folder debug on env dev...
# .Checking folder prod_data on env prod...
# .
```